# Django noob: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index' (Official tutorial)

Tags: python, django

Traceback:

```
Sahands-MBP-2:mysite sahandz$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10e045c08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/sahandz/Documents/Programming/Learning Web development/Django/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/sahandz/Documents/Programming/Learning Web development/Django/mysite/polls/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'index'
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

mysite/polls/views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world, You're at the polls index.")

# Create your views here.
```

File hierarchy:

```
mysite

- manage.py

- mysite
--- __init__.py
--- settings.py
--- urls.py
--- wsgi.py

- polls
--- __init__.py
--- admin.py
--- apps.py
--- migrations
----- __init__.py
--- models.py
--- tests.py
--- urls.py
--- views.py
```

The error baffles me since my files are COPIES of the official tutorial. I have seen that other people have this problem but the offered solutions for them do not seem to solve my problem, such as changing `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),` to `url(r'^$', 'views.index', name='index'),` which only causes another error (second argument shouldn't be a string).

Comment: is your app included in the installed apps in the settings.py file??

Comment: If by "your app" you mean "polls", then no.

Comment: you need to add polls to installed_apps in the settings file else it wont work, as django will go through the files and links to get the url and views, just put polls at the end of the installed apps and then try to runserver again

Comment: So I should just add a string `"polls"` to the list INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yup, at the top or at the bottom as you wish like  INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'polls','other_app1', 'other_app2', etc ]

Comment: Cool. Interestingly enough, both including "polls" in INSTALLED_APPS or, changing to `from polls.views import index` worked. I decided to stick with only including polls though as that solution made more sense.

Comment: yes you can either user polls.views or from . import views,both will work as intended :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from polls.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
]
```

and I hope that you have included polls in your settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ... default values
    'polls',
]
```

Comment: No, I didn't have it in my settings. It surprises me a lot that this is a requirement, yet the official tutorial doesn't talk about it.

Comment: The tutorial [does ask you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#activating-models) to add `polls.apps.PollsConfig` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. You can add `polls` instead and it will still work, unless you want to customize `PollsConfig`.

Comment: Yeah, in part 2. This is part 1.

Comment: Add the polls in installed apps is not related with the import of index in the url patterns.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change it to look like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

This is telling Django to look in the 'views' file and for the view with the name 'index'